# The result of a classic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

For the following series, can we express the result explicitly?
$$\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)^2} = 1- \frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}-\cdots$$

Comment: This is very much on the lines of $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: Yes. we can express!

Comment: Awesome thanks guys!

Comment: @Matthew, that could be an answer after some elaboration.